# ReactJS: One-time initialization of app-level state object: with useState vs. useEffect(..,[])

Tags: reactjs

When my app first loads, I need to initialize the `userInfo` object (in `App.js`) which contains user data.

I am considering 2 options:

`useState` param:

```
function App() { 
    const userInfo, setUserInfo = useState( 
                           () => fetchUserInfo() ); // initial value assigned only 
                                                    // on initial render
}
```

`useEffect` with 2nd empty param:

```
function App() {

   const userInfo, setUserInfo = useState( {} ); // Empty state var

   useEffect( ()=>{
      setUserInfo(fetchUserInfo());
   }, [] ); // Passing an empty array as a second argument to useEffect function call 
            // makes it work like componentDidMount
}
```

Which of these is better for state variable initialization?

Comment: Why don't you profile the 2 solutions to test the performance under different scenarios?

Comment: Can someone answer the posted question as far as best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance wise, these will be pretty much identical - the only real difference is that the `useState` will run *before* the initial render, where-as the `useEffect` will run *after* the initial render.

That said - I'd be using the `useEffect` version. If the `fetchUserInfo` is an `async` call, and you initialise the value in the `useState` hook, then the type of `userInfo` will be a Promise, which is a bit counter-intuitive. Using TypeScript makes this a bit clearer -

```
const fetchUserInfo = async (): Promise<UserInfo> => {
    // http call to fetch user info
}

const App = () => {
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<Promise<UserInfo>>(fetchUserInfo);

    // ----- 8< -----
}
```

If you do this using the `useEffect` hook, then you can type the `userInfo` state object as desired -

```
const App = () => {
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<UserInfo>({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUserInfo = async (): Promise<UserInfo> => {
            const result = await httpCallToFetchUserInfo();
            setUserInfo(result);
        };

        fetchUserInfo();
    }, []);

    // ----- 8< -----
}
```

A third option (and the one I would likely do) is to pull this logic out of your component and put it into a separate hook:

```
const useUserInfo = () => {
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<UserInfo>({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUserInfo = async (): Promise<UserInfo> => {
            const result = await httpCallToFetchUserInfo();
            setUserInfo(result);
        };

        fetchUserInfo();
    }, []);

    return userInfo;
};

const App = () => {
    const userInfo = useUserInfo();

    // ----- 8< -----
};
```